# How could an attacker have gained remote access to my laptop?

Tags: privacy, access-control, remote-desktop, tunneling

I have a 15 yr old daughter who's become not only a certified Microsoft Expert, but by pure accident, it came to my attention she'd long ago created a SPLIT network connection on our internet, HIDDEN from my view. I've had numerous problems such as errors when trying to open certain web pages...email/internet provider/security suite. Even just opening my browser in general, she's been able to make it appear our service isn't enabled. Finally my Internet Provider took hands on tech support & discovered "TeamViewer" & claimed that was just ONE of her techniques. He even had difficulty *locating* my router for quite some time. She managed somehow to gain yet again my laptop, changed all the settings & even did a system restore to correct recent auto updates I'd removed! I'm frustrated, feel I've been defeated by my own child, she's already created quite a history of havoc with compromising banking & has multiple alias user names to perform GOD only knows fraudulently. I truly feel HELPLESS, she's still doing this even after I took away her cell phone. Any suggestions would be appreciated. ALSO***I own a cheesy old Sanyo Incognito, BoostMobile, which is 3g. Please don't tell me it's possible she's able to tamper with my own personal info on IT as well?

Comment: What are you even asking? You should talk to HER.

Comment: This looks more like an interpersonal than a technical problem. Try http://parenting.stackexchange.com. maybe they can help you to fix the problems between you and your daughter.

Comment: While this may not be what you were asking, it might help. Your kid is clearly talented, and more to the point is obviously bored. Point her at the Certified Ethical Hacker qualification, it will take her mind off mischief and will set her on a decent, challenging and respectable career path doing something she loves.

Comment: I have, suppose I left out another one of her "skills". LYING. Denies it all due to the fact that whatever device(s) she's currently using, she's not willing to surrender! I'm unfamiliar with most of this, I'm just trying to get a better idea as to how it can be STOPPED

Comment: or potentially provide her with a wide array of new techniques to use to cause havoc :)

Comment: We can not teach you all the skills you need to secure a network against an internal attacker just in a few paragraphs. But I doubt that a technical solution is really what you and your daughter need. What you two need to fix is your mother/daughter relation, which is outside of our area of expertise.

Comment: @philipp, that was my first thought as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is that I'm afraid that this isn't really a problem that you can solve with technical measures.

If your daughter has physical access to a computer and a higher level of knowledge about how they operate than other people in the household, it's likely she'll be able to affect how they run to her liking.

That said there are some technical means you can take to reduce the risk of her being able to affect the operation of your devices.

One get someone to rebuild the laptop (needs to be someone reasonably technical), set decent passwords, install a firewall and then keep it somewhere she physically can't get it (e.g. locked cupboard and hope she hasn't found online lockpicking resources yet!)

Two consider using other device types.  Things like iPads are less susceptible to being compromised remotely, so again you need to keep physical control of it.  Set a decent passcode not something you use elsewhere and keep the device to hand.  Again if your daughter gets hold of it, she may be able to take control of it (via jailbreaking)

The Sanyo, less likely she'll have modified but it sounds like she has some control over your home network so depending on how much she knows she might be able to intercept/modify traffic on the network.  To combat that, I'd recommend getting a new router from your ISP and make sure only you know the password (again make it something you don't use elsewhere and make sure you don't write it down)

Ultimately you will need to talk to her about this, especially as if she starts trying out "hacking" techniques on other targets, she could easily get into legal trouble depending on what she does.

You might want to (as @chet-s mentions) try redirecting her interest to more noble goals.  If there are any local technical or security groups she may enjoy those?

Comment: For the short run, download a copy of "tails" and burn it to a DVD.  It then runs from the DVD, and doesn't store or use anything from your disk. That will give you a secure but inconvenient way to do banking, etc for a few weeks, until she finds a workaround (;-))